# I get source is not recognized as an internal or external command when trying to activate sandbox

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I am trying to run run a `source` command on cmd on windows.

The code I'm using is:

```
python -m venv sandbox
```

which works fine but then when I want to activate it with:

```
source sandbox/bin/activate
```

I get the error message:

```
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What can I do to activate the sandbox?

Comment: I don't think `source` is available in `windows` Have you tried something like this: `.\venv\Scripts\activate` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-x-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) The __Linux__ command [source](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html) is not available as [Windows command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) as it can be seen also in [A-Z index of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/). The batch file `activate` must be used.